# Why doesn't QCalendarWidget.setDateTextFormat(QDate(), ...) work?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I'm using PyQt 4.4.3.

I've got this code, which should clear all formats in the `QCalendarWidget`:

```
cal.setDateTextFormat(QDate(), QDateTextFormat())
```

According to [the documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qcalendarwidget.html#setDateTextFormat) this should work:

> **`QCalendarWidget::setDateTextFormat(QDate &date, QTextCharFormat &format)`**
> If date is `null`, all date formats are cleared.
>
> **`QDate::QDate()`**
> Constructs a `null` date. Null dates are invalid.

I've tried narrowing down the problem like this:

```
QDate().isNull()
True
cal.dateTextFormat()
{PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(-4713, 1, 1): PyQt4.QtGui.QTextCharFOrmat object}
```

Obviously, `QDate()` is interpreted as being in the year -4713 instead of being `null`.

Any idea what I need to change to make it work?

*Edit:* The problem is, that the calendar isn't reset using this method.

Answer (score 2):

QDate(-4713, 1, 1) is the same as null,

I think that's the way in `QCalendar` to set the default `QTextCharFormat` of the calendar. `QCalendar::dateTextFormat()` is returning a map with all special formats and (I think) the default format.

Or could be a bug, notify to the trolls your problem.